# Writing UTF16 characters from web page to file in Java

Tags: java, encoding, io

I am having trouble in Java writing to file a web page containing UTF16 characters such as FRACTION SLASH which is 0x2044. When I save the page to disk using IE and open with an editor, the character appears written correctly as "4 1⁄2". If I open with a hex editor, I see 00 44 (not 20 44). Any number of other approaches produces (in the file or on the console) "4 1?2". Approaches I have tried include:

```
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(...);
method.getResponseBodyAsString();
EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_16);
IOUtils.toString(method.getResponseBody(), "utf-16");
```

My eventual goal is to write to file a snippet of the page found using a regular expression.

Comment: What are the surrounding bytes?  What is the page content-type?

Comment: Are you sure you mean UTF-16?  Do you really mean Unicode?  (Unicode characters are *typically* encoded in UTF-8 in web pages ...)

Comment: Here are the surrounding bytes:

Comment: Here are the surrounding bytes: 34 00 2D 00 31 00 44 20 32 00 20 00 69 00 6E 00. So yes in fact it is 44 20 as it should be. Here is the URL http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70111440 The header is charset=UTF-8

Comment: It sounds like you're seeing UTF16 _little-endian_, not big-endian.